# Sum values in dictionary from characters

Tags: python

I would like to Read input string, parse it to find the corresponding numeric value in a pre-defined dictionary. Then output the sum of all values read in from the user input. This is as far as I am able to get with what I know. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add the values if lets say the user enters AJE which should produce an output of 16

```
user_input = input('Identify your choice(s): ')


def letterToInt(s):
    letter = {'A': 1, 'E': 5, 'J': 10, 'O': 15, 'T': 20, 'Z': 26, 'YY': 50}
    while True:
        if user_input not in letter or user_input == ' ':
            return 'Error: Input contains an invalid character. Valid input characters are A, E, J, O, T, Z, YY.'
        elif len(user_input) == 1:
            return letter[user_input]
        if len(user_input) >= 1:
            return letter[user_input]


print(letterToInt(user_input))
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to iterate over the user input, check if each character is an index in the dict, and if so, add the value at that index to some accumulator variable.

Comment: Did you really mean to have two characters in `YY`? So `Y` by itself has no value, but  if `YY` is in the input you add `50`?

Comment: You don't need numpy for `sum()`, it's a built-in function. @AhmedMohamedAEK

Comment: You don't need `or user_input == ' '`. since space isn't in `letter`, the `user_input not in letter` test is enough.

Comment: Why do you need `while True:`? You're always returning in every branch, so it never loops.

Comment: Why do you have different conditions for `len(user_input) == 1` and `len(user_input) >= 1`? They both do the same thing.

Comment: Please write your title so someone knows what the "this" you need help for _actually is_.

Comment: @Barmar yes I did mean to have the double Y (YY) my instructor threw that curve ball in there to mess me up I guess.

Answer (score 1):

So I have tried to write this code in a very simple and layman format. I am sure it can be made better.

```
def lettersToInt(user_input):
    input_len = len(user_input)
    sum = 0
    letter = {'A': 1, 'E': 5, 'J': 10, 'O': 15, 'T': 20, 'Z': 26, 'YY': 50}
    for i in range(0,input_len):
        if user_input[i] == 'Y' and i < input_len-1:
            if user_input[i+1] == 'Y':
                p = 'YY'
                sum = sum + letter[p]
        elif user_input[i] in letter:
            v = letter[user_input[i]]
            sum = sum + v
        else:
            print("Not there")
    print(sum)
user_input = input('Identify your choice(s): ')
lettersToInt(user_input)
```

I have obviously added some print statements but you can replace that with return statements. I have considered this specific input for the code, that I have written.
I also understand that for the 'YY' case it will once go in the else part of the code.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm in Germany (different time zone) I posted this last night before I went to bed and woke up and went to work this morning. I normally don't work on my homework until after work and everything else I have for the day which is pretty late which is why I haven't gotten back to you all in a timely manner.

Comment: That is fine, no worries.  I hope the solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = input('Identify your choice(s): ') # your input str


def letterToInt(s: str) -> int:
    # your dict
    letter = {'A': 1, 'E': 5, 'J': 10, 'O': 15, 'T': 20, 'Z': 26, 'YY': 50}
    # you need to convert s to a list rather than use a string
    # then if any letter in s is no in the letter dictionary then raise an error
    if any(k not in letter for k in s.upper()) or s == ' ':
        raise ValueError('Error: Input contains an invalid character. Valid input characters are A, E, J, O, T, Z, YY.')
    # list comprehension to find the values and sum
    return sum([letter[k] for k in s.upper()])


print(letterToInt(user_input))

# Identify your choice(s):  AJ
# 11
```

Comment: Why do you need `list(s)`? You can loop over strings directly.

Comment: How will this ever match the `YY` key in the dictionary?

Comment: Ha, yes, you can iterate over a string. Silly me.

Comment: You don't have to use a list comprehension with `sum`. You can pass a generator expression instead. `return sum(letter[k] for k in s)`.

Comment: @Chris that is just a preference because numpy is headed that direction: `Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.`

Comment: Fair, but as pointed out by @Barmar nothing about this requires NumPy.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Numpy deals with finite collections, but python is more general. And of course `sum()` requires a finite sequence or it will never return.

Answer (score 0):

You `while` loop is completely pointless here. Given an input string `s` all you need to do is :

```
def letterToInt(s: str) -> int:
    letter = {'A': 1, 'E': 5, 'J': 10, 'O': 15, 'T': 20, 'Z': 26, 'YY': 50}
    try:
        return sum([letter[l] for l in s])
    except KeyError as e:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid input letter '{e.args[0]}', valid letters are {','.join(letter.keys())}.")
```

Comment: This will never sum the `YY` key.

Comment: That's true, but I have no idea what he's trying to do with that one and I'm assuming it's a typo...

Comment: As it has been done twice, I doubt it's a typo.

Comment: I'm still waiting for him to answer my question about it.

Comment: Why do you say it's been done twice ?

Comment: @ticster I'm guessing he's seen a duplicate question.

Comment: His error includes it as one of the valid options, and it's not a direct copy and paste.

Comment: Good catch, but I'm too lazy to fix it now XD